# How to display all titles of posts related to a post using tags

Tags: python, django, tags, filtering

I want to display related posts using django filter with tag.
I wrote this filter, but the Queryset won´t filter with title.
Maybe someone can give me a hint how to rewrite my filter to display all posts related with the same tag.

My filter in app_tags.py

```
@register.filter(name='related_posts')
def related_posts(tag):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in = [tag])
    return posts.title()
```

My Html:

```
<div class="containernav">
<div class="mt-3 p-3 bg-white rounded box-shadow  border border-gray">
        <h6 class="border-bottom border-gray pb-2 mb-0">Verwandte Posts</h6>
        <div class="media text-muted pt-3">
            {% load app_tags %}
            <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}">{{ tag | related_posts }}</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I made the same with posts.count and it worked fine. But it won´t display the title of all posts with the same tag.
In the case above it says that Querset has no attribute 'title'.

I also tried this one:

app_tags.py

```
@register.filter(name='related_posts')
def related_posts(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(tags__in=self.tags.all())
```

Html:

```
  <div class="mt-3 p-3 bg-white rounded box-shadow  border border-gray">
    <h6 class="border-bottom border-gray pb-2 mb-0">Verwandte Posts</h6>
    <div class="media text-muted pt-3">
        {% load app_tags %}
        {% for post in posts.related_posts %}
        <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      </p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

models.py

```
 class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
        updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
        content = RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor')
        created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)
        tags = TaggableManager()
```

my app_tags.py

```
from blog.models import Post
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='count_tags_usage')
def count_tags_usage(tag):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in = [tag])
    return posts.count()

@register.filter(name='related_posts')
def related_posts(tag):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in = [tag])
    # iterate over the QuerySet [posts]
    for i in posts:
        return i.title
```

---

My new Html config.:

```
<div class="containernav">
<div class="mt-3 p-3 bg-white rounded box-shadow  border border-gray">
        <h6 class="border-bottom border-gray pb-2 mb-0">Verwandte Posts</h6>
        <div class="media text-muted pt-3">
            {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
            {% load app_tags %}
            <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}">{{ tag | related_posts }}</a>
          {% endfor %}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

My views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Q
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class PostList(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 15


class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'


def tag(request, slug):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"post_list": posts, "slug": tag})


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {})

##def verzeichnis(request):
   ##return render(request, 'verzeichnis.html', {})

def searchposts(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query= request.GET.get('q')

        submitbutton= request.GET.get('submit')

        if len(query) == 0:
                return redirect( 'https://www.code-reminder.com/')

        if query is not None:
            lookups= Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(content__icontains=query)

            results= Post.objects.filter(lookups).distinct()

            context={'results': results,
                     'submitbutton': submitbutton}

            return render(request, 'search.html', context)


        else:
            return render(request, 'search.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'search.html')
```

My urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView





urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
   ##path('verzeichnis', views.verzeichnis, name='verzeichnis'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path("tag/<slug:slug>/", views.tag, name='tag'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'title'

Which is the error message you're getting, was as a result of you trying to do `[queryset].title`.

Django returns QuerySet as a list of objects.

So in your case you can do

```
def related_posts(tag):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in = [tag]).distinct()
    # iterate over the QuerySet [posts]
    for i in posts:
        return i.title
```

**UPDATE**

From my observation, if `views.py` actually renders the actual `template` where you wish to accomplish this, then you might not need the template filter really since you've already done the `filtering` on the `view`

To illustrate

`../tag/cars/` gets a list of `Posts` that contains the `tag` with `slug = car`

here in your `view`

```
def tag(request, slug):
    # returns posts with tags__slug = slug
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"post_list": posts, "slug": tag})
```

Then your `template` becomes

```
<div class="media text-muted pt-3">
            {% for post in post_list %}
            <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE for PostDetail view**

So we can actually ditch the custom template filter for now and pass the filtered `related_posts` as a context in the `PostDetail`

The `PostDetail` view becomes

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        main_post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
        # get all related_post and exclude the main post, makes sense that way
        related_posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in=list(main_post.tags.all())).distinct().exclude(slug=slug)
        # add related_posts to the context
        context['related_posts'] = related_posts
        return context
```

And then update `template` to

```
 <div class="containernav">
<div class="mt-3 p-3 bg-white rounded box-shadow  border border-gray">
        <h6 class="border-bottom border-gray pb-2 mb-0">Verwandte Posts</h6>
        <div class="media text-muted pt-3">
            {% for posts in related_posts %}
            <a href="{% url 'post_detail' posts.slug  %}">{{ posts.title }}</a>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, forgot that. I did that before with my search field also. Thx for the advice.
Now, for some reason i get 3 times the same heading. It now sees that it has 3 related posts, but it posts 3 times the heading of itself. What could that be?

Comment: I just saw that it posts the heading of itself 3 times because the post has 3 tags.
It doesnt see the relation with tags.

Comment: @DobUro if isn't too much to ask, can I see your `models.py` and for `app_tags.py`

Comment: I added my models.py and my app_tags.py. I defined the title as unique

Comment: @DobUro just updated my answer. Change `posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in = [tag])` to `posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in = [tag]).distinct()` and let me know how it goes

Comment: I changed it with .distinct() but it happens again. It shows the heading of itself 3 times because the post has 3 tags.
I also updated my new config in my question above. Maybe it has something to do with the definition of {{ tag | related_posts }}?

Comment: Ok give me some moments to recreate your app locally

Comment: Did you find some answer? I tried also a few things, but couldn't display all the titles.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it displays in some posts some other titles, but not the related ones. Just random some titles.

Comment: @DobUro I have some solutions local, but can I see your `view.py` or just the view calling this particular template and if possible the `url` so I can tailor the answer to suit your logic

Comment: I've added my views and urls files

Comment: @DobUro sorry if this is getting too long. So `views.tag` renders the particular template we're working on, yeah?

Comment: No problem, i'm glad you want to help.
Yes, views.tag i defined in the urls to render

Comment: @DobUro sorry got busy with work stuff, so I've updated the answer again. Let me know if this is what you have in mind, cuz I'm also thinking of a different scenario where you might need to pull related posts - like in a **single post** page.

Comment: No problem, thanks for this update. That piece of code I'm using to display the title of the post in my PostList. It will not display the tag related posts on the post_detail page. I've tried that before.

Comment: @DobUro I think we're getting things missed up :). Cuz we kinda have two solutions already but not applying them as desired. Please walk me through. You have a `PostList` which lists all the post(regardless of tags). So where and how do you wish to display `posts` with related tags ( i.e `related_posts` ) - ( the exact view you're calling for it ).. and is the project public on `Github`.. I can help out. :)

Comment: This part of code in my views.py that you updated render all the tags and displays them to the assosiated post.
But i want then in my Post_Detail page to show the related posts, so every post with the same tag.

Comment: Yes, thats right. I have a PostList with all my posts. There I'm showing the title, content and the tags. 
So now i want to show in my PostDetail page in another box, the related posts. So every post with the same tag. Because till now i have shown the tags, and when i click on them all the related posts are shown.
But now i want to display the titles in a box as related posts.

Comment: Lets say it like that: I have for now for example post 1, post2 and post 3  with one tag COMPUTER. Till now I'm showing just COMPUTER, and when i click ond COMPUTER i show the 3 posts above. But now, i want to show the titles of post1, post2 and post 3 in a seperste box as related posts. You can see my blog at https://www.code-reminder.com

Comment: @DobUro yeah I now get your logic, just updated the answer again to reflect this.. give the **UPDATE for PostDetail view** bit of the ans a try and let me know how it goes. Cheers

Comment: Thats it, thank´s a lot. I´ve learned something new. So we used the old filter and displayed data out of it right?

Comment: @DobUro yeah we used just the default query filter in django at the view level to achieve this. Glad to have helped, I also did learn something myself :). Cheers